# $n$th derivative of fractional part

Tags: derivatives

everyone.

I would like to know are my conclusions right. The question is "*what is the $n$th derivative of fractional part*".

I see the plot of first derivative as a line that is parallel to the **OX** axe and has gaps when **x** is an integer, so I can write it as:
$$\frac{d\{x\}}{dx} = \frac{\{x\}}{\{x\}}$$

Using this and **quotient rule** we can get the second derivative:
$$\frac{d^2\{x\}}{dx^2} = \frac{0}{\{x\}^2}$$

Doing the same things we get the $n$th derivative formula:
$$\frac{d^n\{x\}}{dx^n} = \frac{0}{\{x\}^{2^n}}$$

Comment: by fractional part do you mean $|x|-floor|x|$ or $x-floor(x)$

Comment: The formula is correct, but $0/\{x\}^2 = 0/\{x\}^{2^n} = 0$.

Comment: @Joppy: not exactly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well, aside from the parts that the OP has already figured are undefined.

Comment: @Joppy: so what is the point stating the $=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x$,

$$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

This shows that between two integers, the function is linear ($x-n$).

Taking the first derivative,

$$\{x\}'=1-\lfloor x\rfloor'.$$

As the floor function is piecewise constant, its derivative is $0$, except at the discontinuities, where it does not exist. For this reason, the first derivative of the fractional part is one between integers and undefined at integers.

The next derivatives are zero between integers (as $1'=0'=0$) and undefined at integers.

---

Your expressions do describe this behavior (anyway, the exponent of $\{x\}$ is irrelevant and can remain $1$ for all derivatives). From a formal point of view, they are unjustified as the computation rules that you invoke do not hold for undefined derivatives. So your conclusions are right by accident.